# Views: how to achieve automatic pagination?

Tags: views, paging

I currently have a view that shows some content displayed in the right sidebar but now I have a pager that shows 4 items on every page. The user has to click next every time he wants to see the next 4 items but I want that this paging goes automatically. So instead of clicking next each time, the next page has to show after 30seconds for example.

Any ideas?

Comment: try https://drupal.org/project/scrollable_content

Comment: Hello and welcome. Could you maybe edit your post to make it look like a question. This is Questions & Answers site, after all :) Ideally title should be a question in it's own right, and body should be used for details.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Views infinite scroll](https://drupal.org/project/views_infinite_scroll) module.

> Views Infinite Scroll provides a #586668: Pluggable pagers that enables views infinite scrolling ( autopaging, depaging, endless pages ...you name it) by using jquery.autopager plugin. using this module with views page display will load another page whenever the user reaches bottom of the page.